# Return a substring which is almost the same as the original String

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String literal that contains a sequence of `[a-z]` characters followed by a *digit* character. I want to create a new String literal whose contents will be the same as the old String except the last digit character. How can I do this in the most optimal way in Java?

eg:

```
String str = "sometext2";
String newString = "sometext5"; //The digit part is dynamic and I have that value already computed
return  newString
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this regex

```
\d*$  // 0 or more digits at the end of the string
```

Example:

```
@Test
public void replaceTrailingDigits() {
    String str = "sometext2".replaceFirst("\\d*$", Integer.toString(5));
    Assert.assertEquals("sometext5", str);

    str = "sometext226782".replaceFirst("\\d*$", Integer.toString(897623));
    Assert.assertEquals("sometext897623", str);

    str = "sometext".replaceFirst("\\d*$", Integer.toString(4));
    Assert.assertEquals("sometext4", str);
}
```

As you see in the 3rd test, the regexp allow to append the new number if the original str does not have any tailing digits. If you want to prevent that then you could change the mutiplicity to `one or more` , i.e. `\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(str.subString(0, str.length()-1)).append(digit).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty())
    return (str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)).concat(YOUR_OTHER_DIGIT);
else
    return str; // Handle appropriately what action you want if str is null or empty
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one digit, use substrings

```
return str.substring(str.length() - 1) + nextDigit;
```

If there are several digits, use a regex

```
return str.replaceAll("[0-9]+", "" + nextNumber)
```

If this is in a tight loop, reuse the regex instead of using replaceAll

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one digit, you can do that:

```
return  originalString.substring(0, originalString.length()-1) + newDigit;
```